# Android SQLite Index on Table

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table in a SIP app that stores the call history for all your accounts. I am not a friend of multi-column primary keys, so I put an auto-increment column as my PK.

The first columns of the table are

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CALLHISTORY
    (
        CALLHISTORYID           INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        ACCOUNTID               INTEGER  NOT NULL,
        CALLID                  TEXT     NOT NULL,
        ... + many more columns
```

I get a callId from the CallManager (SIP Server), which is unique for an account (so accountId + callId together build a unique pair).

I set up indices like this:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IX_CALLHISTORY_ACCOUNTID ON CALLHISTORY (ACCOUNTID);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIX_CALLHISTORY_ACCOUNTID_CALLID ON CALLHISTORY (ACCOUNTID,CALLID);
```

I have several queries on this table in the app, some querying only the accountId, some querying the pair (depends on Activity).
Do I really need both indices or will queries that have only the `accountId` in the `where` clause use the unique index too?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a *technical* reason for not using a multi-column PK?

Comment: We are passing the callHistoryId through several methods. Passing only one integer value is simpler and it even works as return value of methods. Which I would not be able to do, if there were always 2 fields involved (or I'd need a new dataholder class for the combined key).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [doc](https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) (1.6 Multi-Column Indices):

> A multi-column index follows the same pattern as a single-column
>   index; the indexed columns are added in front of the rowid. The only
>   difference is that now multiple columns are added. The left-most
>   column is the primary key used for ordering the rows in the index. The
>   second column is used to break ties in the left-most column. If there
>   were a third column, it would be used to break ties for the first two
>   columns. And so forth for all columns in the index. Because rowid is
>   guaranteed to be unique, every row of the index will be unique even if
>   all of the content columns for two rows are the same.

As a result, the index of the ACCOUNTID and CALLID fields already handles the ordering of the ACCOUNTID so creating index on ACCOUNTID is unnecessary in this case.